# Use of Window.postMessage to send auth tokens to embedded apps

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, postmessage

Consider the following scenario.

Website foo.com has an app store. Developers can register their apps there. An app consists of an id, logo, url and a set of permissions.

Users can browse the app store and activate apps. By activating the app they're accepting that the app can act on their behalf with the given permissions. Activating an app gives them an icon in their menu with the app logo/id. It also generates and saves an auth token with said permissions.

When they click the app the respective app url is loaded in an iframe. So far so good. Now the app needs a way to actually act on behalf of the user on foo.com. To achieve this the parent window uses window.postMessage to send the auth token to the iframe containing the app.

The html at the app url will have to includes a small snippet of JS listening for the auth token from the parent window. Once it gets the token it can save it in a cookie / session storage / whatever and proceed to render the app and make calls on behalf of the user.

(note: I didn't specify the auth token. It could be an oAuth access token or a JWT or whatever.)

**Now the question: How is this a terrible and incredible unsafe idea?**

The alternative "standard" approach would be for the app url to initiate a 3 legged oAuth authentication scheme, which would redirect the user back to foo.com (inside the iframe, so now foo.com inside foo.com) to accept the app (which admittedly you could do automatically, since the user has already accepted the app), then foo.com would redirect back to the app url with an authorization code, which it could exchange for an access token.

**I think the suggested postMessage flow is much simpler and cleaner. What downsides am I not seeing?**

Obviously this is no panacea for 3rd party app identification. It only works in the case where the authorization server controls the loading of the 3rd party app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If auth tokens are accessible to javascript, then they are vulnerable to XSS attacks. This is why auth cookies have the httpOnly flag which prevents JS from interacting with them.

An XSS attack on the third party app could reveal the app auth token for that particular 3rd party app.

An XSS attack on foo.com could reveal all app auth tokens.

The standard 3 legged oAuth flow ends with the 3rd party backend issuing something to the browser which authenticates the browser as the respective oAuth credentials. If this is an httpOnly cookie then it's more secure since it's not vulnerable to XSS attacks.

Also, even if the XSS risk is acceptable, you still have CORS issues since the browser would be at the third party domain issuing requests to foo.com